# Setting about:blank as the source of an iframe has side-effects in IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, cors

I have a JS code that creates a hidden iframe, with `src="about:blank"` (so that I don't load the content of the iframe if the user won't click to open it), and when the user wants to see the content of the file, I simply change the `src` of the iframe.

The whole code would be too much to paste, but the gist of it is:

```
// executed on document ready
iframeView = document.createElement('iframe')
iframeView.src = "about:blank"

// executed when the user clicks the button to show the iframe
iframeView.src = "http://example.com/some-url
```

However, sometimes (the keyword being *sometimes* -- ie. about 4/5 of times), on IE the page inside the iframe throws an error and doesn't execute any JS on that page:

> Origin about: not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

I'm figuring that this has something to do with the `about:blank` that I'm setting on pageload. But why? And why only on IE?

**Edit:** Tried setting the `src=""`, that got rid of the error, but the JS on the iframe content page is still not running.